# Creating a choropleth in R measuring violent crimes by county in North Carolina

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, choropleth

I want to visualize violent crimes by county in North Carolina

My dataset looks a little like this:

**subregion violent_crime**

```
alamance    396.39

alexander   130.38

alleghany   137.48

anson   513.65

ashe    78.32

avery   138.51

beaufort    328.74

...
```

Here is my code - so far only the map of North Carolina and its county lines are visualizing.

I was attempting to use only ggplot and maps but I'm running into dead ends

```
...

library(plotly)

library(ggplot2)

library(maps)

library(dplyr)

crime.df <- read.csv(file="B:/Data/visualization/violent_crimes.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")


vcdExtra::datasets


nc <- subset(states, region == "north carolina")

head(nc)

counties <- map_data("county")

nc_county <- subset(counties, region == "north carolina")

head(nc_county)


choropleth <- inner_join(nc_county, crime.df, by = "subregion")

choropleth <- chloropleth[!duplicated(chloropleth$order),]

ggplot(data = nc, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 

  coord_fixed(1.2) +

  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = "gray") + 

  geom_polygon(data = nc_county, fill = NA, color = "white") +

  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)




...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Get NC counties

nc_map <- tbl_df(map_data("county", region = "north carolina"))

# Simulate data since you didn't use dput() as the R section of SO instructs you to do

set.seed(1492)
data_frame(
  subregion = unique(nc_map$subregion),
  crime = sample(50:500, length(unique(nc_map$subregion)))
) -> crime_df

# Join the values to the map

nc_map <- left_join(nc_map, crime_df)

# Plot it

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=nc_map, color="black",
               aes(x=long, y=lat, group=subregion, fill=crime)) +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(name="Crime ", direction=-1) +
  coord_map("polyconic") +
  ggthemes::theme_map() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Consider:

- Binning the crime data into ~5 groups
- Ensuring you're using per-capita info (based on county population since you're focusing on NC)
- Using `dput()` as the SO R section instructs so you can include data
- Trying to isolate errors and provide better error descriptions
- Reading up on projections and try using `ggalt::coord_proj()` with this PROJ.4 string: `+proj=aea +lat_1=34.0207760236743 +lat_2=36.37811477607033 +lon_0=-80.716552734375` vs my lazy way out example.

Comment: Thank you so much!

so I'm still inexperienced with R, and your code is vastly different to that of mine. I don't suppose you'd be able to explain the differences to me?

Comment: The code is really not that different but you didn't include any data (as I said in the answer, SO encouraged you to use `dput()` to aid in making the task reproducible) so it's going to be hard to relate the two. In reality, I get the map data the same way (really), join crime data the same day (for the most part) and just simplified the plotting code a bit (whilst adding in a better map projection, color palette and theme)